# How do I toggle a style change with a button with js?

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

I want to have a button that toggles a style change on my site, but the style won't change back on the second click. this is my html:

```
<button type="button" onclick="stychange()" name="stybut" id="stybut" value="off" >Style Change </button>
```

this is my js:

```
function stychange(){
  if (button.value=="off"){
   button.value="on";
   document.body.style.backgroundColor="#00FF00";
  document.getElementById('ad').style.borderStyle="double";
}

  else {
   button.value="off";}

}
```

Comment: The styles aren't changing back because you haven't written any code to do so in your `else {}` block

Answer (score 3):

You set a class, then you toggle that class, that's how you toggle a style

```js
document.getElementById('stybut').addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('changed');
});
```

```css
#stybut { background : #00FF00; border: 2px double red }
#stybut.changed { background : red; border: 2px double green }
```

```html
<button type="button" name="stybut" id="stybut">Style Change</button>
```

Comment: okay, so if I'm trying to change the styles of more than one element with the same button, I should just put all of the styles in the changed class?

Comment: like I want the button to change the font color, size, background, and border styles of the page.

Comment: Then a class would be perfect, rather than changing every style with javascript

Comment: so maybe I could make a class that has an alternative for body & then put all of the new styles in there?

Comment: Sure, if that's what you want ?